# Making an oscillator for a boost converter

Tags: oscillator, high-voltage

I want to make a boost converter to boos around 1.5 V to 5 V and i read that if the switch in the middle is switched on and off quickly, i can get a continuous increased voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ8MoY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To get the switch to switch on and off quickly, I read that i need an oscillatory circuit, and instead of a switch, a transistor. I found the image below and the left part is an oscillatory circuit. Please tell me how it works (explain the circuit and how each component helps to achieve the oscillation). Also, what does NC stand for on the leftmost transistor ?

[image]

Comment: Where did the circuit come from - it looks incomplete.

Comment: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html

Comment: CAn something like the link above help ?

Comment: That circuit doesn't appear to be on the link provided. Please try and be accurate to avoid wasting time.

Comment: I'm sorry. I linked you to the circuit i can use as an oscillator.

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Just....not in this fashion. You need to put a pull down resistor between the base and the emitter of the coil-driving transistor;; I used a 33k-ohm resistor, to make sure that the driving voltage is symmetrical about the zero mark. 
"It will work" yes it would. But trust me, it is absolutely rubbish. Experiment around with the idea, but please for the love of God don't use this circuit.

This circuit splits into two areas. The oscillator, and the inductor-drive. The weirdly connected transistor, 100nF capacito and the 1k form an Esaki Oscillator. I highly suggest you go read up yourself what that does. Essentially, it depends very much on the properties of the transistor. When the current goes backwards on the transistor(i.e. from emitter to collector), certain transistors, when their bases are open, will exhibit negative resistance, i.e. when the voltage across the junction reaches a point, the current starts to increase rapidly and the voltage across the junction will plummet to a lower value. Now take a resistor and capacitor charging circuit and combine it together. When the 100nF capacitor reaches that particular voltage, the transistor will trigger on and bring the voltage all the way to the holding voltage across the junction. When the capacitor is discharged past that voltage, the transistor shuts right off and allows for the capacitor to charge up again. 
This will cause the circuit to oscillate. Feed the signal through a 100uF to get rid of the DC voltage component and feed it into a transistor. This just acts as a switch to switch current through the inductor. To cut the long story short, the inductor does not like current to change within it, and will induce flyback voltage within it that will charge the output capacitor to hopefully, a higher voltage.

But if you were to build this circuit in real life, with the exact components, you'll find that this is trash in achieving boost voltages of good current.

Answer (score -2):

NC stands for No Connection. This is an esaki oscillator driving the transistor that pulses the inductor.